# generating function for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}i^i (i-1)^{n-i}\}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Hi I am looking for a generating function for the sequence:
$$ \{\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}i^i (i-1)^{n-i}\}_{n=0}^{\infty} $$

Because I am looking for a closed form solution for the series:

$$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}i^i (i-1)^{n-i}\}x^n$$

or

$$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}i^i (i-1)^{n-i}\}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

If I could find an exponential generating function 
$$G(x) = \{n^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^n\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
then I could solve for $F(x)$:

$$F(x) = G(x)*(xD)G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \{\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}i^i (i-1)^{n-i}\}x^n$$

**Edit.**
The larger problem is that I am trying to prove the following equality:
$$n!\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i}i^{n-i} (i-1)^i$$

I can't figure out how to transform from one to the other but numerically they seem to be the same series.

Comment: What sequence are you looking to generate, exactly?

Comment: I am looking for the closed-form soluion to the sum.

Comment: Are you sure it's written correctly? You seem to be missing an obvious simplification.

Comment: The series is $\{\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}i^i (i-1)^{n-i}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$

Comment: What don't you simplify $i^ii^{n-i}=i^n$ ? From there, the solution follows easily.

Comment: sorry, you are right, its $i^i (i-1)^{n-i}$.  I simplified the equation to post it and I oversimplified a bit :)

Comment: @anthonybell possible typo near sophomore's dream.  Is the series $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$ instead?

Comment: You missed a minus sign in the Sophomore's dream identity. According to the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) it is $\int_0^1 x^{-x}\mathrm dx=\sum_1^\infty n^{-n}$.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Can I still use the sophmore's dream here or do I need a different closed-form function for $G(x)$?

Comment: @anthonybell your actual expression which we need to evaluate looks terrible though.(I am referring to the inner $\sum$) I ran some python code. If my code is correct, we get the following, $n=1,s=0$, $n=2,s=5$, $n=3,s=38$, $n=4,s=497$, $n=5,s=8084$... it only gets worse, there is no obvious pattern that I can see.

Comment: It's more than $3\times 10^{17}$ for $n=14$ I am saying that this doesn't even *look* familiar. Even a weird pattern like $2^{2^x}$ which blows up fast too could be spotted. I doubt you will get a nice closed form for this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a computation using the exponential generating function.

Remove the terms $i=0$, they sum up to $\mathrm e^{-x}$ and the terms $i=1$ which sum up to $x$. Perform first the sum over $n$ using
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom nk \frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{\mathrm e^xx^k}{k!}$$
you then get
$$F(x)-x-\mathrm e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\binom nk\left(\frac k{k-1}\right)^k(k-1)^n\frac {x^n}{n!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac k{k-1}\right)^k\frac{\mathrm e^{(k-1)x}[(k-1)x]^k}{k!}$$
A simplification gives
$$F(x)=x+\mathrm e^{-x}+\mathrm e^{-x}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}\left(x\mathrm e^x\right)^k.$$
You can relate this to the [Lambert W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) which is given by the series
$$W(x)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1}}{k!}(-x)^k.$$
So you can write $$F(x)=x\,W'(-x\mathrm e^x)+\mathrm e^{-x}.$$

Comment: anthonybell's edit (after correcting the left side to alternating sign) is asking for the subfactorial numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement  
$(-1)^n \text{Subfactorial}[n]=(-1)^n n! \sum _{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\sum _{i=0}^n (-1)^i (i-1)^i i^{n-i} \binom{n}{i}=(-1)^n \text{Round}\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$

Comment: The main question produces, like Sabyasachi said : 
{1,0,5,38,497,8084,160597,3763626,101666497,3110368328,106303240901} using 
Table[Sum[Binomial[n, i] w^i (w-1)^(n-i) /. w -> i, {i, 0, n}], {n, 0, 10}]  
(* remark the little dance around the 0^0 issue *)  
I have trouble matching this to V. Rosetto's answer, which produces
{1, -2, -7, -73, -895, -14401, -283391, -6598145, -177373183,
-5406289921, -184223743999 }

Comment: Yes, the left side is a solution to a problem which can be cast as a derangement and the right side is a solution to the same problem using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  I wanted to prove that they both produce the same answer.